# unable to connect to oracle using nhibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

I am trying to open oracle connection through nhibernate :

I use the following 
Driver class = NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver
Dialact = NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect

connection string = Data Source=ODOCLDN;User ID=uid;Password=pwd

My nhibernate configuration is working fine with MYsql and sql server .but not with oracle.

With the datasource, user and pwd mentioned in connection string, i am able to login using "SQL PLUS". but not using nhibernate !

Getting the following error : 
Invalid username / password, login is denied.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

"Invalid username/password, login denied" message indicates that you have successfully connected to a database, but failed authentication. Either you've connected to the wrong database, or your userid/password is incorrect. Check the data source in the ODBC manager and make sure it points to the database you need.